# ArcGIS Pro - Does it have some kind of internal cache?

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, import

I've been trying to import a CSV that returned many errors for various reasons (I tried Create Table with imported schema etc.)

Now I'm just trying to import Table to a Geodatabase and pointing to file that looks like this:

[image]

Now I go to my GDB, select Import -> Table, and select the file. The operation is performed successfully but when I open the table I see this:

[image]

The Field5 or extra COD_POSTAL were part of the workflow with previous loading attempts but they definitely do not exist in the file anymore. What's happening here and how to import a CSV without those issues?

Comment: Data is loaded where you tell it to go. If you don't tell it specifically, it might go somewhere hard to find, like a default of the project or the login. I *never* let ArcGIS default on location, just so I don't have to track down my files later.

Comment: The destination was inside my File Geodatabase and the CSV has its own place

Comment: In the layer properties there is a Cache tab where the default setting is "Keep cache between sessions". You may try to change that...You may also have a look in the application options, in the display setting there are some cache setting...

Comment: This is just a guess, but does the csv have an associated schema.ini file in the same directory? I wonder what would happen if there are fields specified in the .ini file that no longer exist in the csv?

Comment: I faced this weird behavior often. The only solution I found is changing file name of csv

Comment: I realised I had to change name of the file to get it working as well @FelixIP.

Comment: Will have a look at the properties, thanks @J.R.

Comment: @lambertj no, there was no schema.ini file in the directory

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to import a load of CSV files using ArcPro and it had problems. My work around was to use the table to excel tool to get the CSV into excel and then run export table to export it into the desired file geodatabase. Whilst this appears to introduce an unnecessary step into the workflow it did mean the import worked without error. It feels like esri haven't quite got ArcPro working flawlessly with text based data.  I found connecting the new export table tool to an iterator serving out tables in a model is incapable of remembering any changes to the field mapping parameter.  Makes it next to useless trying to automate processing with CSV, hence my circuitous route through excel...